# Java Interface with serial port

Tags: java, c, serial-port, listener

I am looking for a library interface to allow me to check what has been posted to a serial port.

To be more precise, I am using a teensy 2.0 to interface with a button. I want to run code within the program without simulating a key press, and thought that printing something to serial would be a easy way to connect to the Java program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've once used [RxTx library](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to establish a communication channel between PC and an external MCU via USB port. Worked fine : )

Comment: seems to be supported until JDK 1.5, fine for one of the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

For my self I'm using the jssc library to communicate with the serial port and it's working fine and I here it'll stay that way here's the link : http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/downloads/list